# MSDN text clarification -reference types are objects

Tags: c#, reference, terminology, msdn

On MSDN, one can read following:

> Reference types are also referred to
>   as objects

I do not understand. I thought that value of reference type points to actual object that lives on the heap, ie at least I would say "Instances of reference types are also reffered to as object". Or am I missing something?

There is also often mentioned "variable of reference type"..but I can have only value of reference type when its e.g.stored in the list.
Do I get it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jargon can be a little confusing here since it's very easy (and common) to be sloppy.

```
class Foo { }
Foo f = new Foo();
```

This defines the reference type `Foo` and the next line defines a reference variable, `f`, that points to an anonymous instance (object) of Foo. Note that working with an object always involves two 'things'. We often simplify a little by saying "f is a Foo object" and while that is practical it is not the full truth.

A few points that may help:

- the instances (objects) don't have a name
- you only name the reference variables
- you cannot pass an instance (itself) as a parameter or return value
- you cannot create arrays of instances
- this means you can only pass/copy/store references
- those references behave exactly like value types (!)

Note that when you look at `interface` types there only is the reference half, there are no 'instances' of interfaces.

Comment: thanks! I was wondering that if method takes parameter of reference type, we say "pass the object to method". But actually the method just takes the reference on the object, is that correct? But many books do say "instance of class with name MyInstance", altought its name of the variable

Comment: Like I said, we're sloppy. Given `void Bar(string s)` we should say "Bar expects a reference to a string instance". But when we say "Bar expects a string" , which is technically impossible, we're still clear and unambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the *reference* points to the object in the heap. The object itself is a *reference type*, because you access it through a reference. (Although the whole redirection through the reference is transparent to you. You might think you're passing around a String object, but you're actually passing around a reference to a string object, which is dereferenced for you.)

The Reference itself (i.e. the pointer, not the object on the heap), is a value type - just to confuse things.

Comment: Maybe there is language barrier now: You say object is reference type..could I say object is data which type is reference? I still believe objects are instances of reference types. Like you have a class X but the object of that type will exist once you create an instance of that class

Comment: objects, all sorts, belong to a group of types called "reference types" if you try to call them anything else, you're going to experience a lot of confusion. But it does sound like a language problem - the key distinction is from value types, which are passed around by value.

Comment: Yes, exactly. But the object is created when I create new value of that type. Class X{} - X is not object, correct? X x=new X() will create object of type X (which is reference type) and the reference to this object will be saved into x variable

Comment: Quite, and because C# knows that variable x is a reference to an instance of type X it will automatically dereference it for you. So unlike some languages, there's no distinction between the object, and a reference to the object. But you are correct.

Comment: re the last sentence: I'm always careful to say ' _behaves_ like a value type', because of the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You could imagine that the word "Reference" just means "Pointer"; a list of objects of your own class contains the references/pointers to the heap allocated objects.

Comment: Yes..but when you have reference type variable, it is not object until you create an instance of that type. So I do not understand why they wrote that reference types are reffered as objects. I mean: value of reference type is just address in memory where the object is

Comment: @lojol: But it's also valid to say that the value of the reference _is_ the instance. That address is just a technical detail (the 'how').